# How to Perform Automatic ALTER in Table on Daily Basis?

Tags: android, mysql, database, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am Developing an Android application which allows user to add the products they want to give away and provide the day they want it to give away.

All of the stuff is done, the thing I am stuck is at how can I remove the items when some one posted it (Lets say after some time e.g after 3 days of when pickup date is passed) Automatically.

I have a column in `POST` table of `STATUS(ACTIVE/INACTIVE)` and another column of `PICKUP_TIMESTAMP`and I wanted a way to automatically check the `PICKUP_TIMESTAMP` daily and if the difference between `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `PICKUP_TIMESTAMP` is greater then 3 days (three days have been passed since `PICKUP DATE`), so I want the `STATUS` of the `POST` to `INACTIVE`.

P.S: I am using `NAMECHEAP STELLAR PLUS PACKAGE OF SHARED HOSTING` for hosting the application.

Comment: Most likely you are looking for MySQL event to automaticly update.. One problem MySQL events are most of the time disabled on shared webhosting accounts.. So you would need to setup a cronjob.

Comment: What you need is event scheduler in mysql [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/) . Once i used it for resetting a table everyday at 11:59:59

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was too thinking of setting up a cronjob, but the problem is that i dont know how to as i havent setup custom cronjobs before, event scheduler is another option but i think cronjobs will be more efficient. Can you guide me or provide some reference material if you can?